# Getting Access to the LinkedIn Jobs API

Tags: linkedin-api

> Sorry, the resource that you are trying to access is restricted. Please contact your LinkedIn Partner Engineering representative to request access.

How can I get access to this service? I couldn't find any contact info and I don't have a partner rep.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply to the partner program:

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Comment: 404 Not Found. Please update the answer.